# Vertical align table and image

Tags: tables, graphics

I'm trying to make a table with an image at one side

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c  p{5cm} }

\begin{tabular}{c c  c | c c } 
 \hline
 $S$ & $R$ & $CLK$ & $Q_{t+1}$  \\ 
 \hline
 0   & 0   & X     & $Q_t$   \\ 
  \hline
 0   & 1   & 1     & 0   \\
  \hline
 1   & 0   & 1     & 1   \\
  \hline
 1   & 1   & 1     & $Error$   \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
&
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{RSflipflop}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Esquema de un Biestable RS síncrono}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I just want to get the image and the table with the same "top" (the image doesn't have white pixels)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `c` column type instead of `p` type, use `[t]` for inner tabular and use `\raisebox` for the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c  c }

\begin{tabular}[t]{c c  c | c c }
 \hline
 $S$ & $R$ & $CLK$ & $Q_{t+1}$  \\
 \hline
 0   & 0   & X     & $Q_t$   \\
  \hline
 0   & 1   & 1     & 0   \\
  \hline
 1   & 0   & 1     & 1   \\
  \hline
 1   & 1   & 1     & $Error$   \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
&
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Esquema de un Biestable RS síncrono}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The outer `tabular` is not needed BTW.

Comment: thanks a lot :), I tried  with \raisebox{-\height} but didn't know about the inner tabular