# Align image exactly beside table

Tags: tables, graphics, tabularx

I'm trying to align an image beside a table. The image is floated below the table.

[image: 'See Graphic Version' Icon dragged below]

This is my code:

```
\multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.8in]{IIIT}}
        &                     &       &    \\
        &  Shubham Rathi      &  Male       &                             \\
        &  Computer Science   &  B. Tech + MS (Computational Humanities)        &      \\
        &  IIIT Hyderabad     &     &         \\
        &                     &      & 
{\includegraphics[width=0.8in]{Icon}}
\end{tabular}
```

This is how I want it to be:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I correct?

Here is the sharelatex file: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57e542d03afea89017192474

Comment: probable dupicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331557/1952 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237699/1952

Comment: Why don't you use another `multirow` for second image? `\multirow{4}{`*`}{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.8in]{IIIT}} & & & \multirow{4}{`*`}\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.8in]{icon}}\\ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ignasi said you can use another `multirow` which provides a construction for table cells that span more than one row.

Here we merge four cells in the first column to insert first image and do the same with the fourth column to insert second image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\geometry{left=0.75in,top=0.75in,right=0.7in,bottom=0.75in}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\label{my-label1}
\bfseries

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.8in]{IIIT}}
        &                     &                                                 &  
\multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.8in]{Icon}}                              \\
        &  Shubham Rathi      &  Male                                           & \\
        &  Computer Science   &  B. Tech + MS (Computational Humanities)        & \\
        &  IIIT Hyderabad     &                                                 & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! But I dont understand how the icon is floated to the left. Can you please explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table with nested tables, exploiting the fact that the default vertical alignment for `tabular` is centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{% stick in the margins
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% left image
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.8in]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}% data in the center
  Shubham Rathi      &  Male                                    \\
  Computer Science   &  B. Tech + MS (Computational Humanities) \\
  IIIT Hyderabad     &  \\
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% left image
  \includegraphics[width=0.8in,height=0.8in]{example-image-b}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
}% end of \makebox

\end{document}
```

[image]